# pyzmq installation error with dependency on gcc

Tags: python, gcc, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pyzmq

I tried installing pyzmq by http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/install/install.html as I want to install ipython. But it has dependency on pyzmq which has dependency on gcc. I already have gcc installed but still I am getting the following error while install pyzmq.

```
   compilation terminated.
   error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

The script also has following in it:

```
If you expected pyzmq to link against an installed libzmq, please check to make sure:

    * You have a C compiler installed
    * A development version of Python is installed (including headers)
    * A development version of ZMQ >= 2.1.4 is installed (including headers)
    * If ZMQ is not in a default location, supply the argument --zmq=<path>
    * If you did recently install ZMQ to a default location,
      try rebuilding the ld cache with `sudo ldconfig`
      or specify zmq's location with `--zmq=/usr/local`

You can skip all this detection/waiting nonsense if you know
you want pyzmq to bundle libzmq as an extension by passing:

    `--zmq=bundled`

I will now try to build libzmq as a Python extension
```

I already have all the above but still issues. I am guessing I have path issues i.e. may be pyzmq is looking at other location but how do I solve this problem

Comment: What OS you are using ?.

Comment: Windows 8.1 and using cygwin

Comment: ohhh. I spent about 2.5 years in Python programming in Windows, but was never brave enough to use cygwin. pyzmq was sometime challenging in "ordinary" Windows, but was always possible to fix. On Linux it works much simpler, but cygwin is not my cup of tea.

Comment: Yaa I should probably shift to Linux but I want to fix this.  Do u knw what path to change as I think pyzmq is going to wrong location to check for gcc

Comment: Sorry, no interest and ability on my side about cygwin :-(

Comment: Ok how would u do it in Linux for path change

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52136/discussion-between-jan-vlcinsky-and-fscore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a huge issue in Windows to install ipython. I would recommend Windows users to never go the pip or easy_install way to install it. I faced a lot of issues like above. I read that it still has dependencies issues on github i.e. via pip.

I got it installed finally by this:

```
Download and install Anaconda

Update IPython to the current version by:
Go to Anaconda directory or look for anaconda cmd & do the following:

conda update conda
conda update ipython
```